# There is a binomial theorem. How about trinomial theorem?

Tags: binomial-theorem

The binomial theorem is $(a+b)^n = (nC_0)a^n + (nC_1)a^{(n-1)}b^1 + \cdots + (nC_{n-1})a^1b^{(n-1)} + (nC_n)b^n$
Is there such a theorem for $(a+b+c)^n$, or $(a+b+c+d)^n$, or $(a+b+c+d+e)^n$, etc.?
If so, what is the proof/reasoning?

Thanks,
Selena

Comment: Yep, it's called the multinomial theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: And you can see the Multinomial Theorem in action just by multiplying out $(a+b+c+d)^3$, or if you don’t have the heart for that, $(a+b+c)^3$. (Be careful to avoid careless errors.)

Comment: Binomial plus associativity gives you trinomial, doesn't it?